# Fill in a column with information by looking up another column

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I am creating a form which my students would submit in a regular basis. In order to minimize student input and error, I am filling in their names on the spreadsheet based on their username. Their username is is collected by Google Form automatically for each submission.

I have a column, with all my student username, and their names. I need to be able to look up a name associated with a certain username and plug it in a column.

[A sample of my spreadsheet can be found here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AOGkSQFa7NR6QjWIUnkvyeT0RP78Eu4l-KO_GdRUHmU/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `=VLOOKUP()` formula:

In cell `B2`: `=VLOOKUP($A2,$I:$K,2,0)`

In cell `C2`: `=VLOOKUP($A2,$I:$K,3,0)`